# Net Core Role Manager: Using the generic type 'RoleManager<TRole>' requires 1 type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I am migrating project from Net MVC to MVC Core 2. I see error below at Role Manager last line. What is the general replace for Role Manager in Net Core?

**Error:**

```
Using the generic type 'RoleManager<TRole>' requires 1 type arguments
```

**Code:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace HPE.Kruta.Web
{

    public class CustomerRoleProvider : RoleManager
    {
```

In fixes, its asking me to utilize NetIdentity in addition to NetCore. Not sure if it's right, to be applying two libraries.

Comment: Don't mix ASP.NET with ASP.NET Core, you should even remove the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` package. If you look at the definition for the `RoleManager<TRole>` class, the type it asks for is for the Role class it manages, the class that contains the RoleId and Name

Answer (score 1):

There's no replacement for RoleManager in Identity core. This is the same as what it was.

By default, you have to pass `IdentityRole` class to the `RoleManager`, which is the default role class in Identity.

If you want to extend the `IdentityRole` and add custom properties to that, you have to derive from `IdentityRole` and add your custom props to it:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string MyCustomProp { get; set; }
}
```

And you have to register your custom Role model in your services:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

With these changes, now where you want to use `RoleManager`, you have to pass your new customized `ApplicationRole` to it. So Identity will manage that class instead of the default `IdentityRole` one:

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

    public HomeController(RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }
}
```

And finally, if you want to extend/customize the `RoleManager`, you have to pass your custom role as the generic parameter of `RoleManager`:

```
public class CustomRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
{
    public CustomRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole> store,
        IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<ApplicationRole>> roleValidators,
        ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
        ILogger<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>> logger) :
        base(store, roleValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, logger)
    {
    }
}
```